# выход из приложения android (webview)

Tags: android

Сделал себе простое приложение для сайта по технологии webview.
Подскажите, можно ли сделать как-то кнопку выхода из приложения : возможно в самом приложении или сделать спец.ссылку на самом сайте ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно переопределить кнопку Back

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
        //для версий начиная с 16
        this.finishAffinity();
        //для версий начиная с 21
        finishAndRemoveTask();

}
```

или реализовать кнопку экранную,если позволяет ui